API for TTM EPS data
I would like to get raw trailing 12 month (TTM) EPS values for individual stocks, going back 10+ years. This is for personal use. I will not be publishing the data. Also, I would like to avoid paying an arm and a leg for the data.
So, something similar to this, except ~free: https://finnhub.io/docs/api/earnings-calendar
I have looked at macrotrends.net EPS charts, but the site only shows the most recent TTM EPS value. I do not see the historical TTM values on the site.
Any suggestions?
